# how to find integer with comma and zeros after that (regex)?

Tags: regex, r, string, stringi

I try to create regex(es) to extract all integers. It can be `6` `-12` bur also `+6.000` or `-5,0` and onother one to extract real numbers which are not integers, for example `3.14`, `-6,26` but no `5.0`.

For finding integers I tried `"^[+-]?([0-9]+)(\\[.,]0{1,})?$"` but it doesn't work on `-6.00`. And I have no idea how to create second regex (how to exclude integers with comas or dots and then zeros). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your integer regex appears to be the backslash(es).  I don't know any regex engine in which you would need to escape the opening bracket of a character class, and you *certainly* don't want to match a literal backslash.  Also, to a regex engine that understands it at all, the quantifier `{1,}` is an uglier, more complex way of saying `+`.

This should do your integer matching:

```
"^[+-]?[0-9]+([.,]0+)?$"
```

And this variation should do your non-integer matching:

```
"^[+-]?[0-9]+[.,]0*[1-9][0-9]*$"
```

In both cases I omitted parentheses not needed for expressing a correct pattern, but if you need to capture parts of the match then you will want to add some back in.  You might also want to convert the grouping parentheses into non-capturing form if you are using a regex engine that supports it.

Also, the real number pattern requires at least one digit before the fraction separator character, per your examples.  It would be easy to convert the pattern to also match strings of the form `.1` or `-.17`.  Similarly, the integer pattern requires at least one zero in the fraction part if there is a fraction separator, and restriction could be removed, too.

Comment: Using `stringi` package in R you have to add `\\`before special sign like `.` but if you want to extract `.` or `,` it seems like using `[.,] work without backslash. Thank you!